# Django models caching? How to disable in tests

Tags: django, unit-testing, django-models

First, the code of my tests.py

```
def test_get_current(self):
    m = Member.objects.create(...)
    q = Question.objects.create(name="q1", text="q1", start_datetime=self.day_before, close_datetime=self.day_after, type=self.type)
    r = Response.objects.create(question=q, text='response')
    expected = q, None 
    #self.assertEquals(expected, Question.objects.get_current(m.id))

    q2 = Question.objects.create(name="q2", text="q2", start_datetime=self.day_before, close_datetime=self.day_after, type=self.type)
    #print Question.objects.all()
    #self.assertEquals(expected, Question.objects.get_current(m.id))
    MemberResponse.objects.create(member=m, response=r)
    print Question.objects.all().exclude(response__memberresponse__member=m)
    print Question.objects.all().exclude(response__memberresponse__member=m)
```

I've got unexpected results in my get_current function, so, I commented it and tried to debug by printing main queryset used inside function and got also strange results:

```
...
Installing index for ... model
[<Question: q1>, <Question: q2>]
[<Question: q2>]
.....
----------------------------------------------------------------------
Ran 5 tests in 3.125s
```

I'm wondering, why QuerySet with the same arguments returns first wrong data, but by the next call - correct and how can I avoid it?

Btw, does django world have something similar to rail's factory girl for creating test data?

Answer (score 2):

[factory_boy](https://github.com/dnerdy/factory_boy) is "a fixtures replacement based on thoughtbot's factory_girl."

If you're coming from Rails, you'll find it works quite similarly to factory_girl. Recommended.

Answer (score 1):

> does django world have something similar to rail's factory girl for creating test data?

I don't know rails well, so I don't really know what a "factory girl" is. But, Django lets you have a fixture loaded automatically, for testing.

From the [documentation](http://docs.djangoproject.com/en/dev/topics/testing/#fixture-loading) here is how you specify what fixtures to load.

```
class AnimalTestCase(TestCase):
    fixtures = ['mammals.json', 'birds']

    def setUp(self):
    # Test definitions as before.
    call_setup_methods()

    def testFluffyAnimals(self):
    # A test that uses the fixtures.
    call_some_test_code()
```

And, oh, you can create fixtures using `python manage.py dumpdata`

And as for disabling cache during development, without affecting the code, you should use "Dummy Caching" as the cache backed.

From the [documentation](http://docs.djangoproject.com/en/dev/topics/cache/#dummy-caching-for-development) you can ask django to use this backend, by the following settings variable:

```
CACHE_BACKEND = 'dummy://'
```

Typically this is put in the localsettings.py of your development system.

Comment: Fixtures are difficult to maintain, that's why I'd prefer to have something dynamic.

Actually, cache is only my guessing for this problem. May be I'm wrong. CACHE_BACKEND setting haven't changed anything, I still get 2 different outputs for the same query.